# Is this masking possible with CSS in all modern browsers?

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, mask

Is it possible to create this html element with just an image and some CSS?
Optionally with the use of an SVG object or some extra divs.
That would work in all modern browsers, including IE/Edge.
Any suggestions?
Or is this not possible at all with IE/Edge and should I use a transparent image for the 'arrow'?

[image: sample]

Comment: Sounds like no per: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Comment: Thanks Robert. I DID look there, but maybe I missed out on another method. So maybe I should rephrase my question?

Comment: @Robert, I tried http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ in IE, but that doesn't work either...

Comment: @RobertLongson do you have an example by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SVG is possibly the most compatible solution currently. There is a possibility to use svg-based clip-path that is referenced in css, but the support is a bit poor (maybe only in FF).

Below is an example that works in IE9+, Edge, newest Chrome, FF and Opera.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/lurowa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<div class="background">
  <svg width="250" height="141" viewPort="0 0 250 141" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipping">
        <polygon points="3 3, 220 3, 220 60, 240 60, 220 79, 220 138, 3 138"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image x="6" y="6" clip-path="url(#clipping)" width="250" height="141" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlu ... AOOlUuZ7GMaji3Y//9k="/>
    <polygon stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="6" points="3 3, 220 3, 220 60, 240 60, 220 79, 220 138, 3 138"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, you are the (lion)king! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to do this responsive as well? Or should I not even look into that? Just a hint would be very nice!

Comment: If you mean that it would fit into many different image sizes and different stroke widths, you can make a function that generates the svg as a string. In this function you can replace any numbers with variables. Is this your intention?

Comment: Sounds promising! I'll have a go with that.